# Same GPUs on Crossfire, different clock speed

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, clockspeed, crossfire

I have two AMD Radeon HD3850 GPUs running on crossfire and I just noticed that they have different clock speeds.
The first one(the one the displays are connected to) has the following clock speeds:
GPU Clock: 300 MHz
Memory Clock: 829 MHz

The second GPU has these clock speeds:
GPU Clock: 669 MHz
Memory Clock: 829 MHz

Is this normal?

Comment: Depends are they exactly the same product? Because it sounds like one is slightly faster and perhaps overclocked and other other is at its stock speeds.  Are both the same type of PCI-E bus?

Comment: They are the exact same product. Could it be the motherboard/PCIe connection?

Comment: I asked two questions.  I need the answer to both in order to answer your followup question.

Comment: Woops, sorry. Didn't see the second question. The specs of the motherboard say "2 x PCIe x16 (blue @ x16 mode, black @ x4 or x1 mode)". Is it the same thing?

Comment: No, its not the same thing, you second card is on a PCIe slot thats is a 1/3 of the speed.  I would gather that is the reason your cards are running at different clock speeds.

Comment: I see, thanks. Do you want to put this into an answer so that I can pick it as correct?